# Can't connect to WiHi hotspot via phone, but from WinPC it's OK

Tags: networking

Good day.
I've created access point on my OrangePi 3 LTS with Ubuntu 22.04 LT and I have zero problems with connecting with my Win10 PCs (MSI laptop and Lenovo Laptop).
But no phone able to connect (iPhone 14, Samsung A-series and Xiaomi) - try to connect, but with no success. Kind a look like password rejection. I try key-mgmt with all options, nmtui and so on. No results at all.
Any advice how to deal with this problem? Thnkx in advance)

I create hotspot with next command:

```
$ nmcli d wifi hotspot ifname wlan0 ssid MyAP password 12345678
```

Here is some data (maybe it will be helpfull)

```
$ nmcli d
DEVICE           TYPE      STATE         CONNECTION
wlan0            wifi      connected     Hotspot
eth0             ethernet  connected     eth0
enx6a6c3d0875c7  ethernet  connected     Wired connection 1
p2p-dev-wlan0    wifi-p2p  disconnected  --
lo               loopback  unmanaged     --
$ nmcli con show
NAME                UUID                                  TYPE      DEVICE
Hotspot             008e104b-c39e-439f-aa64-5471c8fb72e3  wifi      wlan0
eth0                b6e0e584-ee4b-4e3b-8a3d-21598e9c01e9  ethernet  eth0
Wired connection 1  dce6d98b-11dd-33be-9777-95d678fd7564  ethernet  enx6a6c3d0875c7
Ifupdown (eth0)     681b428f-beaf-8932-dce4-687ed5bae28e  ethernet  --
```

/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf:

```
[main]
dns=default
rc-manager=file
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=true

[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Hotspot.nmconnection

```
[connection]
id=Hotspot
uuid=87aec100-99a0-4dbf-9691-8e62fd68063f
type=wifi
interface-name=wlan0
timestamp=1697110741

[wifi]
band=bg
mode=ap
ssid=MyAP

[wifi-security]
key-mgmt=wpa-none;
psk=12345678

[ipv4]
method=shared

[ipv6]
addr-gen-mode=stable-privacy
method=ignore

[proxy]
```

I try key-mgmt options none, wpa-psk, wpa-eap, wpa-none, result was the same. Change this protocol via nmtui, doesn't help.
Only one strange fact - nmcli device wifi don't show two laptops (but they work just fine - ping orange pi no problem)

```
$ nmcli device wifi
IN-USE  BSSID              SSID           MODE   CHAN  RATE      SIGNAL BARS  SECURITY
*       90:86:36:28:65:52  MyAP           Infra  1     0 Mbit/s  0       ____  WPA2
```

ifconfig:

```
$ ifconfig wlan0
wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 10.42.0.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.42.0.255
    inet6 fe80::9286:36ff:fe28:6552  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 90:86:36:28:65:52  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 2272  bytes 496272 (496.2 KB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 1735  bytes 522464 (522.4 KB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Laptop ipconfig:

```
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::3b52:600c:f5e8:b61b%25
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.42.0.208
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.42.0.1
```

ping orange pi:

```
>ping 10.42.0.1

Pinging 10.42.0.1 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 10.42.0.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 10.42.0.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
```

I really don't know that can be helpfull

Comment: Mistake realized and fixed)

Comment: The minimal thing here is too specify a reference to the instruction you used to setup the access point or the current configuration files